# Missing float values in returned JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm working on a web app which uses `Jersey` to exchange data between backend (Java EE and PostgreSQL) and frontend.

I have a `Point` class with following fields:

```
private int id;
private float x;
private float y;
private int r;
private boolean hit;
```

I also have a bean and a service method to get all the rows from the database:

```
//PointsBean.java
@GET
@Path("/getpoints")
public List<Point> getPoints(@Context HttpServletRequest req)
{
    return service.getAllPoints();
}

//PointsService.java
public List<Point> getAllPoints()
{
    return (List<Point>) em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Point p").getResultList();
}
```

However, when I send a GET XmlHttpRequest from Javascript, this is what I get:

```
0: {hit: true, id: 115, r: 2, x: {}, y: {}}
1: {hit: false, id: 116, r: 2, x: {}, y: {}}
2: {hit: true, id: 117, r: 2, x: {}, y: {}}
```

As you can see, the float values are missing. In the DB these columns have `real` type, which should map to `float` to Java.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I checked the server logs, there were no errors.

Comment: Is that _it_? What about checking the values after retrieving them the DB? What about checking the JSON? Have you asked yourself why The Javascript object for the properties are _objects_ when on the server they are primitives? What about the client Javascript side, have you done any checking there? With the information you provided, this is not something that we can solve for you. This is something that can probably be solved by doing some basic debugging on both client and server side.